# Formatting dates and time with Peewee and SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime, peewee

I'm using Peewee to access a SQLite DB. How can I save a timestamp in the following format?

```
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' # year-month-day hour-minute-second
```

(basically: just crop out the microseconds which are present by default)

EDIT: I was able to make this work, using the following in the class definition:

```
created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S))
```

However, I'm still intersted to know if there's a "built in" way of doing this with Peewee, using the 'formats' parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That actually won't work since the timestamp is evaluated at import time (or the time it's declared). Peewee actually doesn't care about the format going *into* the database, since it'll just take the python datetime object and let pysqlite convert it.

If you wanted, the best way would be to subclass `DateTimeField` and override the `db_value` method.

Comment: It does work actually.  Would sublessing make it work without appending () to datetime.now?

Comment: `default=datetime.datetime.now()` -- this will be evaluated *once* and only *once*, not every time an object is created. That is what I mean by it doesn't work.

Comment: OK, thanks for the heads up! Hadn't realized that yet. So subclassing is necessary then.

Comment: We all need the same thing so we all need to subclass? can it not be done at `peewee` level?